# I cannot plot my scraped and cleaned data due: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character"

Tags: python, pandas, csv, ascii, decode

I was trying to encode in scraping part and decode in cleaning but I was having same code or HTTP 400 code, I run code on Spyder 3.7, also tried Jupyter 3 Python. I rea a lot about it online, was trying apply

So my error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/sound/Desktop/dataPlot.py', wdir='C:/Users/sound/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-248-b48d632496ca>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/sound/Desktop/dataPlot.py', wdir='C:/Users/sound/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/sound/Desktop/dataPlot.py", line 16, in <module>
    jobs = sns.load_dataset(needToPlot)

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 428, in load_dataset
    urlretrieve(full_path, cache_path)

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1240, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)

  File "C:\Users\sound\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1107, in putrequest
    self._output(request.encode('ascii'))

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0117' in position 1760: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And my code:
I've started with scraping part to gather data about IT positions and Salary from popular jobspage.

```
#Scraping part

import requests
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?padalinys%5B0%5D=76&page=1'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
all_data = []
for i in range(1, 9):
    url = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?padalinys%5B0%5D=76&page='+str(i)
    print(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    for h3 in soup.select('h3.list_h3'):
        try:
            job_title = h3.get_text(strip=True)
            company = h3.find_next(class_="heading_secondary").get_text(strip=True)
            salary = h3.find_next(class_="salary_amount").get_text(strip=True)
            location = h3.find_next(class_="list_city").get_text(strip=True)
            print('{:<50} {:<15} {:<15} {}'.format(company, salary, location, job_title))
        except AttributeError:
            pass
            
        all_data.append({
                    'Job Title': job_title,
                    'Company': company,
                    'Salary': salary,
                    'Location': location
                })
        
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

After I saved four types of text into dictionary. I tried to clean it so it would be easier to plot it out

```
#Cleaning part

needtoclean = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sound\Desktop\data.csv')

#making all into str, due its mixed with int,float,str
needtoclean['Salary'] = needtoclean['Salary'].astype(str)

cleanedSalary = []
columnSeriesObj = needtoclean['Salary']
for value in columnSeriesObj.values:
    value = value.replace('Nuo',"").replace('Iki','')
    value = value.strip()
    value = re.split(r'[\s,-]+', value)
    if len(value) > 1:  #
        value = (int(value[0])+int(value[1]))/2
    else:
        value = float(value[0]) 
    value = round(value)
    cleanedSalary.append(value)

needtoclean['Salary'] = cleanedSalary



cleanTitles = []
    
for value in needtoclean['Job Title'].values:
    value = value.title()
    value = value.replace('/', ' ').replace('(-Ė)','').replace('(-A)','').replace('(-As)', '').replace('(0s)','')
    value = value.strip()
    value = value.split()

    cleanTitles.append(value)

needtoclean['Job Title'] = cleanTitles
needtoclean.to_csv(r'C:/Users/sound/Desktop/manodata.csv')
```

After cleaning I cannot start plotting due I getting ascii error, not sure which approach should be fine for decoding.

```
#Ploting part
needToPlot = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sound\Desktop\manodata.csv')

jobs = sns.load_dataset(needToPlot)
```

Comment: Please include the entire Traceback

Comment: error shows problem with char `'\u0117'` - first you should check in Google what char has this code and in which encoding. Probably you have text in different encoding then `utf-8` and it has problem to convert it to `utf-8`.

Comment: BTW: should be `sns.load_dataset(r'C:\Users\sound\Desktop\manodata.csv')` ? Doc for [sns.load_dataset()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.load_dataset.html) shows it has to be filename, not `DataFrame` And It can makes problem because it may tread values in dataframe as filename.

Comment: to plot you may need rather something like `sns.relplot(... data=needToPlot)`

Answer (score 0):

You use it in wrong way.

[sns.load_dataset()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.load_dataset.html) is used to load files defined in `searborn` - like `sns.load_dataset('iris')`

To plot it you need use `DataFrame` directly

```
needToPlot = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sound\Desktop\manodata.csv')

sns.relplot(..., data=needToPlot)
```